# How to persists chats in Azure bots webchat control?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I have a scenario where i want to render bot webchat with the context of any bot.
1. How do i allow a conversation in webchat control to appear on multiple channels (teams, outlook etc).
2. How do I get access to chats in webchat control for persisting?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/365) thread for chat history persistence. Also, [this](https://github.com/JasonSowers/ChatHistoryBot-Public) project by Jason Sowers shows a bot displaying chat history in the webchat control.

Comment: Also, could you explain on what do you exactly want to achieve by 'How do i allow a conversation in webchat control to appear on multiple channels (teams, outlook etc).'? Would you mind posting your code on what you have tried so far?